# I have IndustryID like '2,4,5' ...and wants to display results assiciate with those IndustryID. SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

I have `IndustryID` like '2,4,5' ... and wants to display results associate with those `IndustryID`. But the thing is in details table it stores value as `2,4,5` that is comma separated. So using IN operator is only getting `IndustryID` equal to 2 or 4 or 5.

This is my query

```
Declare @IndustryID varchar(50)
set @IndustryID='2,4,5'

select IndustryID,Industry from DetailsMaster 
where (Industry IN (SELECT * from fnList2Table (@IndustryID))))
```

`fnList2Table` is this function here:

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[fnList2Table]
(
    @List varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS 
@ParsedList table
(
    item varchar(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @item varchar(800), @Pos int

    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @item = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @item <> ''
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ParsedList (item) 
            VALUES (CAST(@item AS int))
        END
        SET @List = RIGHT(@List, LEN(@List) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Please provide answer.

Comment: Don't use CSV in databases, it will bite you again and again. Learn to normalize you database instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @Johan: AMEN, brother !!

Answer (score 0):

Use this UDF which converts comma seperated string into row values and just use that in query like ---  IN (select dbo.udf_splitStringToRows(@IndustryID))

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_List2Table
(
  @List VARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delim CHAR
)
RETURNS @ParsedList TABLE
(
  item VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @item VARCHAR(MAX), @Pos INT
  SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))+ @Delim
  SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List, 1)
  WHILE @Pos > 0 BEGIN
    SET @item = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos - 1)))
    IF @item <> '' BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @ParsedList (item)
        VALUES (CAST(@item AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
    END
    SET @List = RIGHT(@List, LEN(@List) - @Pos)
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List, 1)
  END
  RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: .Declare @PackageID varchar(50)
set @PackageID='2,4,5'
select DetailsID,Industry from DetailsMaster 
where (Industry IN (SELECT * from udf_List2Table (@PackageID)))An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function udf_List2Table.

Comment: try this-->   IN (SELECT item from [dbo].udf_List2Table(@PackageID)) while calling an udf database owner should be used  which is [dbo] in my case.   Praveen

Comment: @RahulGolatkar: The function in this answer expects **two** arguments. The first one is the list and the second one is the delimiter, a comma in your case. So the subquery in your example could be rectified like this: `SELECT * from dbo.udf_List2Table(@PackageID, ',')`. Prefixing the function name with `dbo.` in this case is not actually necessary, but still advisable.

Comment: @RahulGolatkar: In fact, this function is only different from yours in that it parametrises the delimiter. Since your ID list is delimited with commas and your function, too, uses comma as a fixed delimiter, I can see no benefit for you from using this answer, unless you are planning to use various delimiters in the future.

Comment: @RahulGolatkar: Ultimately, I have this question: what is *your question* exactly? You've stated what you want, shown what you've got, but not said what the problem is. Your present code seems fine to me.

Comment: @andriy....the problem is cureent query not fetchin the resutt of  '6,5' it should ?....